# Why do I have "unknown type" in MVC project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a C# MVC web application. I have added a code library to the project. I want to create a new class called `TagBuilderCollection` that inherits `TagBuilder`. It will give me a hierarchical structure to have a parent-child relationship for HTML tags I create with `TagBuilder`.

`TagBuilder` is apart of `System.Web.Mvc`. But despite the fact I've added `System.Web.Mvc` as a reference to the library project, and I've added the `using` statement to the top of the class file, I am still getting the intellisense error

```
Unknown type 'TagBuilder'
```

In my MVC project, I'm using `TagBuilder` in the Extensions folder with no reference issues. I just can't figure out why I can't reference it in my code library???

Comment: Does your project compiles?

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: No. But because of your comment, I went ahead and built the project even though there was an error. When I did, it failed but gave me the message that it recommended that I add `System.Web.Webpages` as a reference. I did that, and now it is working! No idea why `System.Web.WebPages` is needed, but it is apparently.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. Usually when you have this weird intellisense errors you want to make sure that your code compiles :) By the way `System.Web.WebPages` is already included in the default MVC4 project.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: Yeah. That's what I get for taking Intellisense's word for it! And you are correct. `WebPages` is apart of the web app, but was not apart of the code library I am creating the class in. I guess `WebPages` is some kind of dependency for the `Tagbuilder` class.

Comment: This happens because System.Web.WebPages is just a namespace. More than one DLL can add classes to a namespace. You see this often with the MVC projects because the assemblies for MVC extend a lot of the base namespaces. You can see this by using the Object Browser inside of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `System.Web.WebPages` as a reference to the library. Now it's working.

Despite the intellisense error, I attempted to build the project. VS kicked back an error saying that the error was (paraphrased) "forwarded to System.Web.WebPages. Try adding that as a reference." So I did. And now it works. I don't know why that mattered, but it did.